# Impossible to get Safari browser's cookies and website data mode with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, privacy

I want to get Safari cookies and website data mode with javascript. 
Cookies and website is 4 mode : "Always block", "Allow from current website only", "Allow from websites I visit", and "Always allow"

[image]

I have tried many times without success. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to know what this setting is set to? Perhaps you are only interested in knowing if some feature is limited by this setting?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to do with javascript mode?
If you just want to check cookie is enabled or not, use `window.navigator.cookieEnabled`.